# How to implement the follow RMDB query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

My team started to use MongoDB now and wanna migrate some sql to Mongo.
For example, I have an order table and has the fields price and quanty.I want to query the price*quanty greater than 100. sql is like below

```
select * from Order where price * quanty > 100;
```

How to use "price * quanty" this kind query in Mongo?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this doc, but there are no the two scenarios in it...

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) operator to use aggregation expressions within your query:

```
db.orders.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      { $multiply: ["$price", "$quantity"] },
      100
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As JohnnyHK points out you can use *$expr*, but as an alternative you can also use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation) to first create a new field that is the product of two other fields:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
     { $set: { product: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } } }
   ])
```

*Note: $set is new in 4.2 and just an alias for $addFields*

Then add a *$match* stage that only matches documents with the new `product` field meeting your condition:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
     { $set: { product: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } } },
     { $match: { product: { $gt: 100 } } }
   ])
```